# Модели в подпапках в yii

Tags: yii

Каким образом сделать так, чтобы модели можно было влаживать в папки. Например, все модули форм вложить в папку form. Доступ оп идее должен быть такой $model = new Form_Login; ?

Comment: хм..  а чем структура YII не нравится?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> влаживать

**вкладывать**

В конфиге добавляете секцию `import` с этой папкой в виде алиаса:

```
<?php return array(
    'name' => 'AppName',
    ...
    'import' => array(
        'application.form.*',
    ),
    ...

);
```

И, собственно, и все. Все указанные в `import` алиасы будут преобразованы в пути, просканированы, и при поиске какого-либо класса Yii поднимет кэш содержимого этих директории, и при обнаружении одноименного файла загрузит его. При этом не требуется никаких дополнительных движений, только `$instance = new Class;` и все.

Если нужно импортировать директорию/файл во время рантайма, это можно сделать через `Yii::import()`.

P.S. Именовать классы с подчеркиваниями - bad practice.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Насчет "влаживать": http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-3238.htm.
Насчет вложенности моделей в папки. Описанный способ вами я знаю, но тогда мне придется каждый раз, создавая новую папку, лазит в конфиг.
Насчет "Именовать классы с подчеркиваниями" - сама модель именуется без _. Этот символ заменяет /. папка_имямодели. Так сделано в kohana

Comment: @Александр Железно..., кохана-то здесь причем?

> но тогда мне придется каждый раз, создавая новую папку, лазит в конфиг

Потому что Yii местами встает на дыбы и отказывается работать как хотелось бы. Проще всего будет сделать сервис, который будет получать все папки в каком-то корне и импортировать их, а затем запихнуть этот сервис в preload.